# $O_1, O_2, O_3, O_4$ circumcenters for triangles $AQM , MBN, NCP, PDQ$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let ABCD a parallelogram and $M, N, P, Q$ on $AB, BC, CD, DA$ and $O_1, O_2, O_3, O_4$  circumcenters for triangles $AQM , MBN, NCP, PDQ$. Show that $O_1O_2,O_3,O_4$ is a parallelogram. In a rectangle it's easy to prove.
I tried to costruct line bisectors but I didn't find anything.[image]

Comment: Think about the circumcenter as the concurrency point of the perpendicular bisectors of the sides, and it becomes a bunch of parallel/perpendicular conditions that you have to gather.

Comment: @TheBestMagician I tried but I didn t succeed

Comment: Hint: Assume points $M$, $N$, $P$ are fixed. The goal is then to show that no matter where $Q$ is, the corresponding $O_1 O_4$ is parallel to (fixed) $O_2O_3$.

Comment: @CalvinLin In a rectangle is easy to prove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signs in this solution will depend on location of points relatively to parallelogram sides. Using vector projection one can eliminate this disadvantage.

[image: drawing]

$$GA=AI+IG=AI+EJ=AE \cos A+O_1E\sin A \Rightarrow O_1E=\frac{GA-AE\cos A}{\sin A}$$

$$HB=HL=KF-LF=O_2F \sin A - BF \cos A \Rightarrow O_2F=\frac{HB+BF \cos A}{\sin A}$$

$$EF=EM+MF=AE+BF=\frac{AE+EM}{2}+\frac{BF+MF}{2}=\frac{AB}{2}$$

$$O_2F-O_1E=\frac{HB-GA+(AE+BF) \cos A}{\sin A}=\frac{NB-QA+AB\cos A}{2\sin A}$$

Slope of line $O_1O2$ about line $AB$ is $$k_{12}=\frac{O_2F-O_1E}{EF}=\frac{NB-QA+AB\cos A}{AB \sin A}$$

Using analogy: slope of line $O_3O_4$ about line $CD$ is $$k_{34}=\frac{O_2F-O_1E}{EF}=\frac{QD-NC+CD\cos C}{CD \sin C}$$

$$QA+QD=AD=BC=NB+NC \Rightarrow QD-NC=NB-QA \Rightarrow k_{34}=k_{12}$$

$CD$ is parallel to $AB$, therefore $O_1O_2$ is parallel to $O_3O_4$.

Answer (score 2):

Trivially, $O_1O_2O_3O_4$ is a parallelogram when $M,N,P,Q$ are the midpoints of the sides. Let's call this the middle parallelogram.
[image]

(Sorry for not labeling the points, I'll use the names for the points in this drawing.)

From the middle parallelogram, let's move $E$ to where we want it to be.

$I$ is the intersect of the perpendicular bisectors of $CE$ and $CF$, and $K$ is the intersect of the perpendicular bisectors of $DE$ and $DH$. When we move $E$, only the line segments $CE$ and $DE$ change.

Therefore, when we move $E$, the gradient of $IK$ will stay constant, so it will always be parallel to $JL$ just like it was in the middle parallelogram.

Repeat this process for $F,G,H$ and all the sides of $IJLK$ will be parallel to the sides of the middle parallelogram.